# Insert fail logs

Tags: sql-server, logs

Is there a way to view fail inserts to a SQL Server database?  I am seeing that a number of my inserts are failing and I'd like to recover that data if it's possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, SQL Server does not log failed transactions, and that data is gone.

You need to implement error handling. This would be a tip of the iceberg question, but here are some links for you to read.

- [TechNet : Using TRY...CATCH in Transact-SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Erland Sommarskog : Error Handling in SQL 2005 and Later](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html)
- [Bill Graziano : Handling SQL Server Errors](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/handling-sql-server-errors)

Come back and ask a new question if you have some *specific* problem implementing your own logging of failed inserts.